# install the .NET environment on ubuntu 10

Tags: .net, ubuntu, mono

I'm .NET developer, I want to install the .NET environment on ubuntu, I found some equivalent to some applications of windows on ubuntu(more simple, of course), like:

1. Visual Studio : MonoDevelop
2. CSC : Mono

the rest I will found after, for start it is what I need.

how do I to install Mono and MonoDevelop? I found a lot of tutorials on internet how do this, but each one works differently, and nothing was worked fine. I'm looking for an tutorial, tips or an guia that really teach how do I to it works fine.

Currently, the mono that I'm using is native on ubuntu, I get the following when I call it:

```
The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded.
It should have been installed in the `/usr/lib/mono/1.0/mscorlib.dll' directory.
```

and the MonoDevelop returns:

```
Package: monodevelop (for debian)
Error: Dependency not satisfied: mono-runtime (> = 2.10.1)
```

Comment: Do you mean Ubuntu 10.04 ? If yes, go to www.badgeports.org and let them do the magic for you

Comment: @EugenRieck: Yes. Thanks for your reply. I follow the steps from http://badgerports.org/help.html but when I run it on terminal I get the following error: `Reading package lists ... ready Building dependency tree Reading state information ... ready E: Could not find package mono`  how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed it simple by running:

> sudo apt-get install mono

It's all installed and copy to correct folders with all dependencies.

May be you should uninstall the package you have with:

> dpkg -P mono

and re-install it again..

Comment: Does not works for me, I get the following error: `Reading package lists ... ready
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... ready
E: Could not find package mono ` maybe some anything that need I to update on my ubuntu?

Comment: Does this command 
>apt-cache search mono 
provide any output ? Does you see at least 'monodevelop' package listed ?

Comment: No. does not provide any output about mono. how to fix this?

Comment: Please make sure that you checked: 'Community-maintained open source packages' in UpdateManager tool (or you can check it from 'synaptic'). Do this: 1) >sudo update-manager 2) Click on 'Settings' on low-left 3) In 'Settings click on 'Ubuntu Software' (first tab) and make sure you checked 'Community-maintained Open source software'. Then run >sudo apt-get update   and then check again if at least 'monodevelop' package listed. Alternatively you can check the IanNorton answer below for different source of mono. It's not hard to do - all idea it that you need to add the source of mono packages.

Comment: I updated my ubuntu packages with:`sudo apt-get update` and then installed with `sudo apt-get mono-develop` worked fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to run a **[parallel mono environment](http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments)**. This lets you run a different version of mono, it's libraries and monodevelop while not interfereing with the mono that comes with ubuntu.

You can **[build this yourself](http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments#Building_Sources)** or you can try **[my pre-built packages](http://inorton.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/mono-2-10-8-and-monodevelop-2-8-5-1-packages-for-ubutnu-oneric/)** for ubuntu 11.10 by adding:-

```
deb http://void.printf.net/~bredroll/pmono ./
```

To your /etc/apt/sources.list and then running:-

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install pmono-monodevelop pmono-mono pmono-scripts
```

Then run things in your parallel mono environment by running:-

```
$ pmono monodevelop
$ pmono mono myapp.exe
$ pmono bash
```

See also:- http://inorton.wordpress.com/category/mono/pmono/